# Change SVG component on press with React Native

Tags: react-native, hook, use-state

**Background**

Pretty simple question: I want to create a "like" button in RN. To do this I have to separate components which are SVG files. One is just the outline of a heart, the other one is filled.
The screen in which I'm trying to build this button is a Function component so I should use hooks. I know about state but don't know how to properly use it.

**What I need**

A Touchable Opacity component which holds an onPress method which changes the image component when pressed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function Like() {
    const [isLiked,setIsLiked]=useState(false) ;

    const handleLikePress=()=>{
        setIsLiked(!isLiked) 
    }

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLikePress}>
            {isLiked? <FilledHeartSVG/>: <OutlineHeartSVG/> } 
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

```
 by default, we are showing an outline of a heart SVG
 when press event trigger we are changing isLiked state value
 if isLiked is true then show  filled heart SVG 
 if isLiked is false then show  outline of a heart SVG 
 FilledHeartSVG and OutlineHeartSVG is just example use your SVG there
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below, here i have made a toggle for the text but you can change it to your image component, also the callback prop can be used if you want to use that outside the LikeButton

```
const LikeButton = ({callback}) => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
      setLiked(!liked);
      if(callback)
      {
        callback();
      }
    }}>
      <Text>{liked?"Liked":"Like"}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

You can tryout this snack which uses icons
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/likebutton